# How would I send a python variable over a webhook

Tags: python, discord.py, webhooks

I'm trying to send a variable over a Discord webhook in python, but instead of actually it being the text I set it as, it just says the variable on the webhook. Here is what I'm setting the text to be:

`embed["description"] = "Username: {username}"`

And here is what it's sending instead
[image: Discord]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean: `f"Username: {username}"`?

Comment: I think maybe you should edit the title of your question such that it represents the string formatting with variable problem? I am sure others will benefit more, when they get such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make it an `f` **string**

```
username = 'Alex'
embed["description"] = f'Username: {username}'
```

Now, the `{username}` will be replaced with `Alex`.

Comment: Note that f-strings were introduced in python 3.6